# ajax call vulnerable to xss attack

Tags: ajax, security, web, xss

I have a simple web application in which I make a call to a java servlet using ajax from a jsp page (via post). In the servlet I take data from the database and formulate a JSON and retreive in the jsp page . I then use eval function to parse the json and display the data in the division using the innerHTML property . Somehow, this approach seems to be vulnerable to xss attacks . Can someone provide some pointers on how XSS attck can be prevented in this use case?

Comment: no its just comments posted by users that are stored in a backend database

Comment: Why are you using EVAL to begin with?

Comment: yes eval's a culprit ,agreed.Can you suggest alternatives to eval so that I can convert my json back to a javascript object.

Comment: Maybe you could use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: I don't think innerText gives me the flexibility to add html and css to the division I am updating.Correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  There are a few ways of [preventing DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Either you have to html encode the data on the server or the client.  HTML encoding data in the database **should always be avoided** because it changes the value of the data and will affect how the data is sorted, ect.  [XSS is an output problem](https://sitewat.ch/en/Blog/5) so it should be solved by the code that is building the HTML,  which in your case is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers support JSON.parse().For older browsers use json2.js.

You should also properly encode the JSON so values cannot break out of quotes etc. Find a decent json encoder and use that on the server side.

Comment: he is writing the value to the page.

Comment: Yes, but directly using eval can easily be just as big a problem